# Settings.gradle(.kts) is missing in the root directory

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I am try to import existing flutter project in Android studio. I get this type of error when building project.

Here is my complete error prompt-

Executing Gradle tasks as part of a build without a settings file is not supported. Make sure that you are executing Gradle from a directory within your Gradle project. Your project should have a 'settings.gradle(.kts)' file in the root directory.

any help??

Comment: You've likely selected the wrong directory.

Comment: Did you get lucky solving this error ? suddenly I have it! and don't know what is missing